# Power BI: Compare two columns in a table visual

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to compare two columns in Power BI and only color when there is a difference from one column to another.

[image]

Like this:

[image]

The pictures are from:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Compare-two-columns-in-a-table-visual/m-p/272761#M122058

I saw the solution there (the link above), but since it was asked two years ago, I wanted to check if there is a better solution or color formatting I am not aware of.

I have to compare over 70 pairs of columns. That is why I was checking if there is an alternative that does not require to create a column per pair

Or how would you approach it?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Still you can use the conditional formatting option.

Comment: @mkRabbani Are you referring to the answer from the link, correct? I have to compare over 70 pairs of columns. That is why I was checking if there is an alternative that does not require to create a column per pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional formatting has improved. You can now conditionally format a column by other fields. So you can define a difference measure and use that:

```
Diff = IF ( SUM ( Sales[Sales - DB] ) = SUM ( Sales[Sales - File] ), 1, 0 )
```

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Comment: Thanks! I like the coloring option. The answer is similar to the link in the sense that you have to create a column (per pair).  I have to compare over 70 pairs of columns. That is why I was checking if there is an alternative that does not require to create a column per pair.

Comment: You need to specify that in the question or write a new post with that information included. Depending on how your data is shaped, you might be able to write a single measure that works for many pairs but it's hard to say without you sharing more details.

Comment: Good call. I have added such detail to the question. I still need to check each pair individually (so not only care if they are different or not but also differentiate that if they are different on which column. So, I doubt that a single measure would apply) I know it is not ideal, and so far, creating a calculated field/column per pair seems to be the only option.

Comment: If they are indeed separate columns in your data table, then that sounds right. If the data is in an unpivoted format, there *might* be better possibilities depending on how your visual is built.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this.

Is there a way to compare two string columns in the matrix table using "new measure"

= if(Column A = Column B, True, False)

Comment: Is this a new question or an answer to the original question...?

Comment: Hi Aron,

This is a new question.

Comment: Ok. Even though your question is similar to the original question, you are better off creating a brand new question. That will put your question in the "new" and "unanswered" categories and you are more likely to get help.