# Power BI - Conditional formatting on column name/value

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting

I want to see if it is possible to create a conditional formatting on a column name/value on a matrix table in Power BI. I have attached a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve. The column name would be highlighted based off of today's date.

[image]

**UPDATED**
If it is not possible to highlight the column name, is it possible if all the values are highlighted based off the date on the column value?

Comment: As far as I understand, you can conditionally format the values but not the column headers.

Comment: @AlexisOlson is it possible to highlight the values based on the date of the column?

Comment: Yes. You can highlight the values but not the column header.

Comment: @AlexisOlson can you show me how you would highlight the values based on the date of the column?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870437), you can define a measure to use in a [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) rule.

Use a measure like

```
IsToday = IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTable[Date] ) = TODAY(), 1, 0 )
```

and write your rule to highlight based on `IsToday` equals `1`.